# Rotate line using ArcTan2 over the +- 180 degree boundary

Tags: c#, math, rotation, geometry

I have a line witch rotates to the current mouse position with a set speed (x degree per calculation = rotating angle).

I do this by calculating the current angle of the line and the target angle with the mouse cursor.

Than i set the new current angle according to this logic:

```
            if (this.currentAangle < this.targetAngle)
            {
                if((this.currentAangle + this.rotatingAngle)> this.targetAngle)
                {
                    this.currentAangle = this.targetAngle;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.currentAangle += this.rotatingAngle;
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                if ((this.currentAangle - this.rotatingAngle) < this.targetAngle)
                {
                    this.currentAangle = this.targetAngle;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.currentAangle -= this.rotatingAngle;
                }
            }
```

So if the gap between the current angle and the target angle is bigger than rotation speed, add the rotation speed. if it is smaller, set the current angle to the target angle.

This approach works for almost all angles. except for the case that current and target angle are on the left side (one beeing around -180 and the other around beeing at 180)

So i changed my code accordingly:

```
            if (Math.Sign(this.targetAngle) != Math.Sign(this.currentAangle) && Math.Abs(this.targetAngle)>2)
            {
                Signum = -1;
            }

            if (this.currentAangle < this.targetAngle * Signum)
            {
                if((this.currentAangle + this.rotatingAngle)> this.targetAngle)
                {
                    this.currentAangle = this.targetAngle;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.currentAangle += this.rotatingAngle;
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                if ((this.currentAangle - this.rotatingAngle) < this.targetAngle)
                {

                    this.currentAangle = this.targetAngle;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.currentAangle -= this.rotatingAngle;
                }
            }
```

But this only solves it by some part. If i move the mouse "slowly" of the "9 o clock" line. It works perfectly. But if i move my mouse fast, it "jumps" immediately to the target.

I have the feeling that it is due to wrong calculations. And i guess that i can solve the problem with a lot of if-else clauses.

Is there a way to solve this smarter? With some math? My feeling tells me that adding some 2*PI somewhere might be helpfull but i cant really get it to work

Comment: Pastebin of the complete code
https://pastebin.com/a5iXk6kt

Comment: Sorry my mistake I forgot to delete the `fabs` ...  you are missing normalization of angle difference. two angles can be 180deg apart of each tops if not you need add/remove 360deg from the difference until they are ... something like `da = a1-a0; while (da>180.0*deg) da-=360.0*deg; while (da<-180.0*deg) da+=360.0*deg;` but there might be also something else wrong too....